# Change font size in PropertySheet

Tags: visual-c++, propertysheet

How can i change the font size in my header in PropertySheet? I'm NOT using MFC by the way. I've googled around and haven't found answers. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `embarcardero`, just go to properties, click on `Font` and click on the ellipse that will appear on the side, then the font-setting will show. Likewise with `borland`.

Otherwise, you can just code it. Here's the code for `embarcardero`, `nameOfcomponent`->`Font`->`Style` << `fsBold`. This is to make your font bold for instance.